# Search exact string , match it .If no matched entry add parameter also if partial match modify python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file /etc/sysctl.conf and want to search for below 2 strings. If no such strings found we need to append file with same . If no exact match found we need to correct it or delete line and add. If exact match found no action on file.
I am unable to replace in file. Please guide.

Search Strings :

net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh = 15728640
net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 16777216

My Code

```
          #/usr/bin/python
import os,datetime,shutil,re

num1 = 'net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh = 15728640'
num = "net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 16777216"

''' This Programme checks ipfrag value in /etc/sysctl.conf .
It also checks parameter in /proc/net/ip4

'''

date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
find_low_thresh=re.compile(r'net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh\s*=\s*15728640')
find_high_thresh=re.compile(r'net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh\s*=\s*16777216')
find_low_thresh1 = re.compile(r'net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh*')
find_high_thresh1 = re.compile(r'net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh*')
low_count=0

for i, line in enumerate(open("/etc/sysctl.conf", "r")):
    for match in re.finditer(find_low_thresh1,line):
        print(match.group())
        S3=match.group()
        print(S3)
        low_count+=1


if low_count == 0:
    print("Count is Zero and no match found")
        with open("/etc/sysctl.conf", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write( "net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh = 15728640\n")


elif low_count == 1:
    print("Counter is one")
    with open("/etc/sysctl.conf", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(re.sub("net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh","net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh = 15728640\n"))
else:
    print("Do Nothing")

#####################################################

if os.path.isfile("/etc/sysctl.conf." + date):
    print("File already exists")
else:
    print("It Does not exists,Copying file")
    shutil.copy("/etc/sysctl.conf", "/etc/sysctl.conf."+date)

if os.path.isfile("/etc/sysctl.conf." + date):
    S2="File already exists"
    print(S2)

else:
    print("File copiped")
```

Comment: You say "If no exact match found we need to correct it or delete line and add". What circumstance would it be deleted?

Comment: sotime if we are unable to replace with desired strings, we can first delete partial match line and then add it . Like if net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 0000 but not exact net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 16777216 then in this case we can delete line then add.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach using python data types instead of just string regex (it's too easy to mess up regex and ruin the structure of the file).

Working with a fake example file:

```
# hash comment
 ; colon comment

one = 1
net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh = 1234
another = ok
```

code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

setting_map = {
    'net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh': 15728640,
    'net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh': 16777216,
}
found = {setting: False for setting in setting_map}
to_write = []

def good_setting(setting):
    return '{} = {}'.format(setting, setting_map[setting])

with open('sysctl.conf') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()  # remove newlines

        try:
            setting = line.split('=')[0].strip()  # remove spaces if present
            value = int(line.split('=')[-1].strip())
        except Exception as e:
            # you probably don't want to print, but i put it here for demonstration
            print('could not parse line "{}"; exception: {}'.format(line, repr(e)))
            # keep it as-is
            to_write.append(line)
            continue

        if setting in setting_map:
            found[setting] = True
            if value != setting_map[setting]:
                print('FOUND "{}" with value "{}"; overwriting with "{}"'.format(
                    setting, value, setting_map[setting]
                ))
                to_write.append(good_setting(setting))
                continue

        to_write.append(line)

# opening as 'w' will wipe the file, but we're re-writing every line
# or you can write to a different file if you'd like
with open('sysctl.conf', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(to_write))
    f.write('\n')
    for setting in setting_map:
        if not found[setting]:
            print('ADDING "{}"'.format(good_setting(setting)))
            f.write('{}\n'.format(good_setting(setting)))
```

output:

```
could not parse line "# hash comment"; exception: ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: '# hash comment'")
could not parse line " ; colon comment"; exception: ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: '; colon comment'")
could not parse line ""; exception: ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''")
FOUND "net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh" with value "1234"; overwriting with "15728640"
could not parse line "another = ok"; exception: ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ok'")
ADDING "net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 16777216"
```

file after:

```
# hash comment
 ; colon comment

one = 1
net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh = 15728640
another = ok
net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 16777216
```

Comment: if starting line has # or other character in ex. #net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh': 15728640 . it will will still add . Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub()` takes 3 parameters, but this isn't the real issue here. You wont actually replace the text you're trying to replace with a simple file write without first seeking to the offset that you want to write to with the `seek()` function. This is an issue for you though because your replacement string is longer than the original and you'll likely end up writing over data you didn't intend to. Another issue is you chose to open the file for append, which in some systems will ONLY append to the end of the file, which i'm sure is not your intention.

All you really need to do is open the file and copy the data to a variable.
Then, attempt to find the string and replace it. Finally, write the entire thing back to the file.

```py
def write_over():
    file_name = '/etc/sysctl.conf'
    new_string = 'net.ipv4.ipfrag_low_thresh = 15728640'

    fh = open(file_name, 'r+')
    data = fh.read()

    result = re.search(r'net\.ipv4\.ipfrag_low_thresh\s?=?\s?[0-9]*', data) # check this regex, it may not be exactly what you need
    if result:
        if result.group(0) == new_string:  # if the string is exact match, do nothing
            fh.close()
            return
        data = data.replace(result.group(0), new_string + '\n') # else replace with new string
        fh.truncate(0) # this will clear the contents of the file
        fh.seek(0)
        fh.write(data) # write the new data in its entirety to the file
        fh.close()
    else:
        fh.write('\n' + new_string) # if the line was not in the file at all
        fh.close()
```